# How do you use Simpson's rule?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry

Using Simpson's rule and and interval of d =$0.5,$ approximate the area of the region bounded by the curve defined by $y = $$\sqrt{x+2}$ and the $x-axis$

This is in my geometry book, however there wasn't even an example on how to use simpson's rule what I only know is substitue $x=1$ and get $y=\sqrt{1+2}$ and so on until i reach $x=4$ whenever I type simpson's rule on the internet it always shows calculus which makes me more confuse[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) the rule is given as $$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx= \frac {b-a}6\left[f(a)+4f\left (\frac {a+b}2\right)+f(b)\right]$$  The integral on the left is the area you are looking for.  The simplest application is to set $a=1,b=4$ and evaluate the right side.  This violates the $d=0.5$ you are asked for.  To have $d=0.5$ you need to break the range up into smaller intervals.  It is not perfectly clear whether $d=0.5$ means $b-a=0.5$ or $b-a=1$ because there are two subintervals used in Simpson's rule.  I will use the second.  In that case, you apply it once with $a=1,b=2$ and get the area for that range of $x$, again with $a=2,b=3$, and again with $a=3,b=4$ and add the results.